# FrontAccounting API Module Redirect to login

Tags: php, slim

I'm working with FrontAccounting. On my local environment it works fine with no issues. I have uploaded to ubuntu-server and everything works fine (from browser), the only issue is i cannot access api part:

I am using [this api module](https://github.com/andresamayadiaz/FrontAccountingSimpleAPI)

[image]

sample setups:

[image]

I'm lost somewhere. application works fine on browser only the api module keeps responding with HTML response.

I've tried to enable logs to preview what went wrong and i did not succeed

```
$error_logfile = __DIR__.'/tmp/errors.log';
$debug          = 1;    // show sql on database errors
$show_sql       = 1;    // show all sql queries in page footer for debugging purposes
$go_debug       = 2;    // set to 1 for basic debugging, or 2 to see also backtrace after failure.
$pdf_debug      = 0;    // display pdf source instead reports for debugging when $go_debug!=0
```

As working through i found out issue is with my nginx server:
with php -S works fine, in nginx works on browser still api not working

[image]